# How can I express this in terms of Gauss-Hermite Quadrature?

Tags: normal-distribution, approximation

I am having the following expression. This is the PDF of Nakagami-Lognormal Distribution. I want to express in terms of Gauss-Hermite abscissas and weights. How can I do it?

$$f_Z(z)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2m^mz^{2m-1}\exp(-\frac{mz^2}{\Omega})}{\Gamma(m)\Omega^m}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\lambda\Omega}\exp\left(-\frac{(\ln \Omega-\mu)^2}{2\lambda^2}\right)d\Omega$$

Comment: Well, first of all you're going to need an integral over $(-\infty,\infty)$, so try to think about how you might change variables to achieve that. One thing to keep in mind is that you'd really like to see $e^{-\Omega^2}$ times something, so seeing as you have $\ln(\Omega)$ in the square, try $u=\ln(\Omega)$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

So your integrand is (for fixed values of everything except $\Omega$):

$$c_1 \exp(-c_2/\Omega) \Omega^{-m-1} \exp(-c_3 (\ln(\Omega)-\mu)^2).$$

To get a Gaussian-like thing, change variables to $u=\ln(\Omega)$, so $du=d \Omega/\Omega$ giving

$$c_1 \exp(-c_2/e^u) e^{-mu} \exp(-c_3 (u-\mu)^2)$$

where the new limits are $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Now merge the linear part into the quadratic and complete the square:

$$c_1 \exp(-c_2/e^u) \exp(-c_3(u-\mu-m/(2c_3))^2) c_4$$

Then change variables to $w=\sqrt{c_3} (u-\mu-m/(2c_3))$. Then your integrand is a bounded smooth function times $\exp(-w^2)$ and the domain of integration is the whole line. So this form of the problem is amenable to Gauss-Hermite quadrature.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Would you please complete the answer. I mean what is the final Gauss-Hermite form after the second change of variables, $w=\cdots$.

Comment: @SresthaNarayanan I'd rather not, it is a lot of managing constants...

Comment: Is it also not possible to do the change of variables as : $u=\frac{\ln \Omega -u}{\sqrt{2}\lambda}$

Comment: @SresthaNarayanan You could, but you'll still want to change variables again to merge the linear part into the quadratic so that the remaining part of the integrand is bounded.